# gen_rosinstall.py generating invalid install files?

Tags: ros, installation, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not entirely familiar with how the rosinstall files are supposed to look, but it looks like the gen_rosinstall.py file is generating invalid rosinstall files.

1.) If I just run rosinstall from the site directly, I get the error:

ahhhhhhhh, yaml parse error: mapping values are not allowed here
in "", line 5, column 8

2.) If I download the empty file, I needed to remove the spaces between the key and value pairs  on line 5.

I.e. Line 5 Goes from:
[{'svn': {'local-name': 'ros', 'uri': 'https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros/tags/ros-1.4.6'}}, {'svn': {'local-name': 'ros_comm', 'uri': 'https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_comm/tags/ros_comm-1.4.5'}}]

To:
[{'svn':{'local-name':'ros', 'uri':'https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros/tags/ros-1.4.6'}}, {'svn':{'local-name':'ros_comm', 'uri':'https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_comm/tags/ros_comm-1.4.5'}}]

3.) Then, the first 4 lines are:

Do the parsing 
Check if rosdistro exists 
Check if stack exists 
Check if variant exists

I had to remove these also from my rosinstall file that I had saved.

Is this a bug? Should I register this with the bug-tracker?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9672/gen_rosinstall.py-generating-invalid-install-files?/) by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 765 on 2011-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug.  It looks like debugging code got released.   Please file a blocker ticket on the [ros trac](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/newticket?component=ros_release&type=defect)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2011-04-08**:
Okay thanks, I've filed a bug. I was a little nervous filing the bug right away incase I was misunderstanding/mis-using rosinstall.